# Solved a type issue but not understanding what was done exactly

Tags: typescript

I ran into a very common type error around `cid => cid` as below.

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export const func1 = _.wrap(
  _.memoize(() => _.debounce(func2, 1500), cid => cid),
  (func: Function, cid: number) => func(cid)(cid),
);
```

```
Argument of type '(cid: Parameters<T>[0]) => Parameters<T>[0]' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => any'.ts(2345)
```

The error is rather straightforward, but it was difficult to do something because I had trouble understanding the initial code. I managed to fix the error as below:

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export const func1 = _.wrap(
  _.memoize(() => _.debounce(func2, 1500), ((cid: any) => cid) as any),
  (func: Function, cid: number) => func(cid)(cid),
);
```

I'm glad that I stumbled upon a workaround but I'd like to know what was it that fixed things.
My main obstacles are:

1. Trouble understanding what exactly corresponds to what. Is it `cid => cid`  that had `(cid: Parameters<T>[0]) => Parameters<T>[0]` type, which was wrong?
2. `Parameters<T>[0]` is considered as a type, but the `[]` is new to me.
3. What kind of syntax is at `func(cid)(cid)`? Is it like `func(cid)` is another function?

Comment: Which version of lodash are you consuming?

Comment: @tmhao2005 lodash@4.17.20 and @types/lodash@4.14.165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out there was a trivial problem with your implementation above as following:

Here is the `memoize` signature:

```js
<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, resolver?: (...args: Parameters<T>) => any): T & MemoizedFunction;
```

Let have a look the `resolver` as the 2nd argument would take a function param which has argument is  the argument of `T` which is `() => _.debounce(func2, 1500)`.

`() => _.debounce(func2, 1500)` is a function which has no any param which means your `resolver` should have no param too.

In short, the correct implementation should be (based on the defined type which also can be wrong if your code run well):

```js
export const func1 = _.wrap(
  _.memoize(() => _.debounce(func2, 1500), () => {}), // the 2nd param would take the argument of the 1st param `() => _.debounce(func2, 1500)`
  // or if you wish to have parameter for 2nd argument, you should add for the 1st one too
  // _.memoize((id) => _.debounce(func2, 1500), (id) => id),
  (func: Function, cid: number) => func(cid)(cid),
);
```

Regarding your question about what is `func(cid)(cid)`? Since `func` is set as `Function` type so it's simply able to get called twice (`func(cid)` returns another `Function`, then it was called another time `func(cid)(cid)`)